# Using argcomplete after partial parsing

Tags: python, argparse

My Python script takes a filename as an argument and then adds more arguments depending on the content of this file. This is done by

1. Adding the fixed arguments (i.e. `filename`)
2. Calling `parser.parse_known_args()` to retrieve the fixed arguments
3. Adding some dynamic arguments depending on the content of `filename`
4. Calling `parser.parse_args()` to parse the remaining arguments

Now I would like to enable tab completion using `argcomplete`. Therefore, I want to call `argcomplete.autocomplete(parser)` right before step 4. However, this doesn't work since `argcomplete` apparently only runs until step 2.

So my question is: Is there a way to autocomplete arguments that are added to the `ArgumentParser` after `parser.parse_known_args()` but before `parser.parse_args()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [argcomplete](https://github.com/kislyuk/argcomplete) and how it works. You could place it after `parser.parse_known_args()` and before `parser.parse_args()`, but it would not benefit you all that much, because it runs your script and inspects the `parser` provided to figure out options for autocomplete. It does not pass any arguments (i.e. what has been typed on the command line so far) to the script.

That when argcomplete gets invoked, your script would have no idea about what `filename` was passed and what other arguments should be dynamically added.

Also if you had any `required=True` arguments already added to the parser prior to running `parser.parse_known_args()` you would indeed never run `argcomplete.autocomplete(parser)` because execution of the script would have failed on the former before reaching the latter (again, for purpose of autocomplete the script runs w/o any parameters being passed to it).